# How to create the screen in optimized way?

Tags: blackberry, border

Hello everybody I am trying to create a screen (to see the image [click here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a0d61a80d8.jpg))
I have set it's backround image also created required list components which are click able by extending Field class. Now my problem is I am not able to set that rounded white color as backround of the list. Please help me. And also because I am new to the blackberry please also tell me the optimized way to create this screen.

Answer (score 0):

i think like this

1) header bar - create manager and embed 2 buttons and 1 label in it
2) bottom bar - create a global class that contains the buttons and define a method that responds to the click event of these buttons
  call that class in this main screen
3) for middle part use a list field which is scrollable